# How to add a maven project as a dependency to another one

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I've just started a java project, in which I'd like to use the classes of **[another project](https://github.com/dcm4che/dcm4che)**.

My `pom.xml` looks like this so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What would be a good way to add that other project as a dependency in mine? Should I download all of its compiled `jar` files and add them one by one in my `pom.xml` as dependencies? Or is there a better option?

I was thinking of downloading all the `jars`, putting them into a directory (e.g. `lib`) and somehow referencing that entire directory in the `pom.xml`, so if there's a new version of the project mine depends on, I only have to change the contents of that `lib` folder for the new `jars`, and don't have to edit the `pom.xml`. Is it an option? If so, how to do that?

Or most importantly, what is the proper way you suggest doing it?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html; in short: declare a dependency and let maven handle all the other stuff. Do *not* manually download and copy any jars (edit: unless that other project is not published to Maven Central, then there might be a few steps in between).

Comment: Base on the project you are referencing the first feature/request I would make is that they make their dependencies available via Maven Central..that would help all contributors/consumers etc. to use their library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the latest version of this project, I suggest you build it yourself. Because it seems they are releasing to Sourceforge and maintaining the code actively.

Each time you want to upgrade the version, you have to get the latest source code (via git) and use `mvn install` command on this projects root pom.xml to install it to your local maven repo. This project is configured as multi module maven project, using install on the root pom.xml will install all the sub modules.
On your projects pom.xml you can use `mvn versions:use-latest-releases` to update all your dependencies to the newest version. This command will automatically upgrade dependency versions for you.

To add a project as dependency follow Marvins link.

Comment: `mvn install` is the way to go. You can even switch to a tag, if you want to install a specific version.